# How to force extraction of only specific private class members?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I want Doxygen to force extraction of only specific private class members. I know about the [`EXTRACT_PRIVATE`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extract_private) option, but it extracts *all* private members. I want to be able to pick and choose which private members I want to be extracted.

For example something like the following:

```
class Foo {
private:
  /** @forceextract
    * @brief Something about this function.
    */
  void foo1();

  /** @brief Something about this other function.
    */
  void foo2();
};
```

`foo1()`'s documentation should be extracted though it is private, but `foo2()` should be left alone.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147668/doxygen-private-function), you can use a labeled conditional section, then *not* include the section under ENABLED_SECTIONS:

```
class Foo {
private:
  /** @brief Blah blah blah */
  void foo1();

  /// @cond COND1

  /** @brief This will be hidden! */
  void foo2();
  /** @brief So will this */
  void foo3();
  /** @brief This should be hidden too */
  int fooInt;

  /// @endcond
};
```

Instead of having to add a condition to all the fields you want included AND adding all those conditions to the enabled sections list, you can just add conditions to fields which you do *not* want included. In this example, if you do not add COND1 to the ENABLED_SECTIONS, it should honor the fact that COND1 is not set, and thus will not include "foo2()" in the documentation. Make sure you still set EXTRACT_PRIVATE.

Edit: Sorry, my original answer said "include" instead of "not include" in regards to the section.

Comment: I have literally thousands of private members in my application of which I want to extract only a handful ones. I am afraid it isn't practical to add conditions to the ones I do not want included.

Comment: You can group as many private members as you want under a single condition variable. If they're not in any particular order (like documented first), then yes, this won't really be practical. Another way to do it would be to simply not include the doxygen style documentation on members which you do not want documented (you can use regular comments) and specify HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS = YES (unless that's also not an option).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a somewhat roundabout alternative for this.

```
class Foo {
#ifdef DOXYGEN_EXTRACT
public:
#else
private:
#endif
  /** @forceextract
    * @brief Something about this function.
    */
  void foo1();

private:
  /** @brief Something about this other function.
    */
  void foo2();
};
```

Then define `DOXYGEN_EXTRACT` (or whatever tag you prefer) under `PREDEFINED` in the Doxyfile.

A couple of limitations/problems:

- The members are shown as `public` in the output, not `private`.
- You should remember to explicitly specify the access specifier for the next member.