# Doxygen "Reimplemented from" and private method

Tags: doxygen

I'm using doxygen to generate documentation for a project i'm working on.

When reimplementing a public method from a base class in a subclass, doxygen adds

> Reimplemented from MyBaseClass.

at the ends of the method's documentation.

This is excepted behavior and this is what I want. However but it doesn't do the same thing when reimplementing a private method. Is there a way to do so ?

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562763/doxygen-hiding-private-protected-method-and-tips) could help you out.

Comment: @fiscblog Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't :(. The method is extracted, but the "Reimplemented from ..." is not appended at the end of the function's documention.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the member
    INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB 
to
    YES
.

> Constructors, destructors and assignment operators of the base classes will not be shown

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It simply removes the "Reimplemented from ..." from the public method reimplementation, and does nothing for private method. Still, thanks.